# What are usages of overwrite mode in text editors?

Tags: keyboard, text-editors

So I overwrote my previously typed text accidentally for the thousandth time in my life probably, because I accidentally pressed `Insert` before that. Which made me think what are usages of this functionality anyway I have not used it a single time in my life? Does it has any purpose besides randomly messing up your already typed text?

Comment: To edit and replace text that is in a column based format. For example list of numbers ...

Comment: This might be interesting for you: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/51473/replace-mode-in-a-text-editor-do-we-still-want-it-insert-key

Comment: It comes in handy sometimes when writing code and other applications as others have stated. It's mostly a legacy concept, and people are just not used  to using it, if they were it would probably used more often.